Does direct realism rely on colour realism?
It seems to me that, to avoid the idea that the 'colouring' of the data one receives is in the mental representation of it, one would have to say that colours exist in the real world, so the data is already coloured. Are there any ways of justifying both direct realism and the idea that there are no actual colours in the world, just wavelengths and spectral reflective properties?

Colours are the way how we experience certain electromagnetic waves. Why to avoid this idea?

Yes. Just because colors are not part of a fundamental physical description does not mean that "there are no actual colors in the world" any more than that there are no actual tables in the world. Objects and properties do not have to be fundamental to be real, objective and mind-independent, compound and derivative entities can be directly perceived just as well, see Allen, A Naïve Realist Theory of Colour.

If we didn't perceive something somehow, we wouldn't know it exists at all.

@JoWehler Because colours aren't the electromagnetic waves. 'Redness' seems to be uniquely an experience rather than a wavelength of light. You would have to depart from direct realism
